# Настройка выпадающего меню

Tags: php, меню, menu, radio

Есть выпадающее меню на сайте сделаное на PHP. После выбора авто в `Title` оно не добавляется, а остается как и есть "Марка". А хотелось, чтобы поле само закрывалось. Но я так понимаю, это надо на JS.

Сайт: [здесь](http://xn---93-5cdk6e1a.xn--p1ai/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/**
 * Displays form field for refine search form.
 *
 * @param string $label
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $values
 * @param string $type
 *
 * @return void
 */


  function cp_refine_fields( $label, $name, $values, $type ) {
    if ( in_array( $type, array( 'radio', 'checkbox', 'drop-down' ) ) ) {
  ?>

    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>">
        <label class="title"><?php echo esc_html( translate( $label, APP_TD ) ); ?></label>

        <div class="handle close dashicons-before"></div>

        <div class="element">

            <?php
            $options = cp_explode( ',', $values );
            $optionCursor = 1;
            $checked = '';
            ?>

            <div class="scrollbox">

                <ol class="checkboxes">

                    <?php
                    $cur = ( isset( $_GET[ $name ] ) && is_array( $_GET[ $name ] ) ) ? array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET[ $name ] ) : array();
                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                        if ( $cur ) {
                            $checked = in_array( $option, $cur ) ? " checked='checked'" : '';
                        }
                    ?>
                        <li id="<?php  $string = esc_attr($option); $string1 = str_replace(' ', '', $string); echo mb_strtolower($string1); ?>-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php  $string = esc_attr($option); $string1 = str_replace(' ', '', $string); echo mb_strtolower($string1); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option ); ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> />&nbsp;<label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>[]"><?php echo esc_html( $option ); ?></label>
                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->
                    <?php } ?>

                </ol> <!-- #checkbox-wrap -->

            </div> <!-- #end scrollbox -->

        </div> <!-- #end element -->

        <div class="clr"></div>

    </li>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>">
        <label class="title"><?php echo esc_html( translate( $label, APP_TD ) ); ?></label>
        <input name="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" type="text" minlength="2" value="<?php if ( isset( $_GET[ $name ] ) ) echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $_GET[ $name ] ) ); ?>" class="text" />
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </li>
<?php
    }
}
```

Вот код jQ нашел но как сделать чтоб вместо марки писало то что отмечено.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.handle').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next('div.element').animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 500
        );

        jQuery(this).toggleClass('close', 'open');
        return false;
    });



    jQuery('div.element').mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 500
        );

        jQuery(this).hide();
        return false;
    });


    <?php foreach ( $_GET as $field => $val ) : ?>
        jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.handle').toggleClass('close', 'open');
        jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.element').show();
    <?php endforeach; ?>

});
```

Comment: isset( $_GET[ $name ] )  - не долго ваш проект продержится)))) А по вашему вопросу, лично у меня ваше меню не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос ни как не относится к php.
Вам нужен подобный плагин [jQuery Multiple Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/)
[**GitHub**](https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/)